# why insert() function take o(n) time in vector in c++

Tags: vector, insert, c++14

### Not find proper answer

[geeks for geeks link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-insert-function-in-c-stl/)

**why insert function take o(n) time complexity while we are providing the position where to insert??
can anyone tell me the reason......
in my point of view is this happened because of iterator ,,,, may be  i am wrong but i want clarification on it..**

i read it from the given link but i didn't find the proper answer of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory in a `std::vector` is typically represented as an array, so inserting a new element in the middle of the array without overwriting anything requires that all data after that point be shuffled to the right (linear complexity). Inserting at the end with `push_back()` is *usually* constant time, unless the internal capacity of the vector's array needs to be increased, in which case it is again linear.